# class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am encountering the ClassCastException when trying to retrieve Keycloak User Resource.

```
 private void updateMerchantInKeycloak(String keycloakId, Merchant merchantDTO) { 
log.info("updateMerchantInKeycloak : keycloakId : " + keycloakId + ", merchantDTO: " + merchantDTO); 
UserResource userResource = KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users().get(String.valueOf(keycloakId)); 
       log.info("KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource(): " + KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource()
            + "\nKeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users()" +
    KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users());
    log.info("updateMerchantInKeycloak got userResource : {}", userResource);
    UserRepresentation userRep = userResource.toRepresentation();
    log.info("updateMerchantInKeycloak got UserRepresentation");
    if (Objects.nonNull(merchantDTO.getEmail()) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(merchantDTO.getEmail())) {
      userRep.setEmail(merchantDTO.getEmail());
    }

    if (Objects.nonNull(merchantDTO.getStatus()) &&!"".equalsIgnoreCase(merchantDTO.getStatus())) {
      if (merchantDTO.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTIVE)) {
        userRep.setEnabled(true);

      } else if (merchantDTO.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.SUSPENDED)) {
        userRep.setEnabled(false);
      }
    }
    if (Objects.nonNull(merchantDTO.getRegisteredMobileNumber())
            && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(merchantDTO.getRegisteredMobileNumber())) {
      userRep
              .getAttributes()
              .get(Constants.MOBILE_NUMBER)
              .set(0, merchantDTO.getRegisteredMobileNumber());
    }
}`
```

The error occurs when code attempt to retieve the user Resource:

`KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users().get(String.valueOf(keycloakId));` 
This line is throwing a java.lang.ClassCastException between java.lang.String and org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal.

here is the code of KeycloakAdminClientUtils:
`KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext() .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

I've ensured that the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() should return a KeycloakPrincipal, but it seems to be returning a String, causing the ClassCastException.

**stack trace**: ERROR GlobalRestExceptionHandler : class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLCla I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve the error.

I tried by replacing the line KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users().get(String.valueOf(keycloakId));. with the line KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users().get(keycloakId); but still the same error occurs. Note: here keycloakId is String.

Comment: Please format this illegible mess properly.

Comment: @user207421 done formating

Comment: What's the type of `KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users()`?

Comment: @tgdavies KeycloakAdminClientUtils is a class which contains method RealmResource

Comment: @tgdavies the type of KeycloakAdminClientUtils.realmResource().users() is UsersResource.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the line

`KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext() .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

where the authentication principal is a String. There could be several reasons for this, you need to decide what you want your code to do if principal is not a KeycloakPrincipal. For starters, how about changing the above line to a conditional

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

if ((auth != null) && auth.isAuthenticated() && (auth.getPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal)) {
    return (KeycloakPrincipal) auth.getPrincipal();
}
throw new IllegalStateException("Expected a KeycloakPrincipal but instead got " + auth);
```

With your current code you'll then run into that IllegalStateException, but we don't know if a string principal is a possible, but invalid state in your application (e.g. "anonymous"), or if your security setup is broken and a string principal should never occur.